# SQLALchemy - a list attribute (or problematic? FK table)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My data feed looks like this:

```
{['item_id': 1, ... 'price': 123, ... ],
 ['item_id': 1, ... 'price': 124, ... modifiers: [1, 2, 3],
 ['item_id': 1, ... 'price': 125, ... modifiers: [100, 150, 500 ... ],
 ['item_id': 2, ... 'price': 200, ...],
 ...}
```

Those are basically some `item`s that can be modified - think of it as a car that can be modified with extra stuff (e.g. AC, electronic windows etc), but can be sold on its own too, along with their prices in an auction.

My (current) `item` class look like this:

```
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    price = Column(Integer)
```

I'm not sure how to capture the `modifiers` there. I know I can create a `Modifier`eg:

```
class Modifier(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'modifiers'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

But then how do I achieve the following:

1) The tables would have to be many-to-many relationship as any modifier can be applied to any item, and any item can have multiple modifiers.

2) **More importantly** - I need to differentiate `['item_id': 1, ... ]` from `['item_id': 1, ... , modifiers: [1, 2, 3]` relatevely efficiently (I would be potentially scanning hundreds of millions of such items a day).

***End-goal*:**

Keep a price histogram of what each of those items (base item & modification combination) 'go for'. It's not a simple "base item price" + "price of each modifier", because for instance some items are no longer in production, yet the value of the base item would be higher than value of the modified item. Hence I need to quickly identify which item & modifiers combination are we talking about, and assign a current price to it.

***End-goal 2*:**

Knowing the average price of what the item goes for, being able to efficiently determine whether it is worth buying. By efficiently, I mean really mean efficiently, because as I said, it would potentially be hundreds of millions of different auctions a day and so it is not really feasible to do something like:

```
buy_list = []

for a in auctions:
    item_id = a['item_id'] #not good. this doesn't include modifiers
    price = a['price']

    #way too slow I think. If 10^8 auctions, would create a 10^8 calls to db.
    buy_price = some_query(item_id) 

    if buy_price < price:
        buy_list.append(a)
```